# Quarto restricted access to webpages

Tags: r, web, r-markdown, quarto

I am wondering how to create restricted webpages with Quarto, so users are required to log in with their usernames and passwords.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/6052 There's nothing in quarto itself that can help you do that. You would need to control access at the server level. It depends on know you are deploying the report to know exactly what's possible.